# Razor XHTML "&" Character encoding bug

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i am loving this new view-engine and one of the coolest features is everything is encoded by default. but there is something i don't understand,
let us say i have created this HTML paragraph

```
<p>
       this is a test Paragraph for both Development & Production
</p>
```

now if i inspect element in firebug i get

```
<p>
  this is a test Paragraph for both Development  &amp; Production   
</p>
```

which is correct but if i view source code in browser 
i get

```
<p>
  this is a test Paragraph for both Development  & Production   
</p>
```

and i try to validate the page with W3C validation i get the error of "&" character as none valid.

now my document is as i think set right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11     /DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I'd start by checking into that "everything is encoded by default" claim, as it appears to be somewhat inaccurate.

Comment: And after having revised the claim, I'd look for an accurate method of determining what your view *actually* renders to the client, so you don't have to guess. Curl and Fiddler come to mind.

Comment: @Pointy how is that claim inaccurate?

Comment: @marcind well, apparently it *doesn't* encode "everything" by default.  I didn't mean to imply that the good people behind the framework are lying; I meant to suggest that the OP may have misinterpreted their literature.

Comment: @Pointy good point. The tutorials should be clearer on that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default Razor will encode everything that it writes, not everything in the page. Since Razor things the text inside the P tags are HTML it will not do any encoding to it.

Take a look at the following example for a better understanding of the difference:

```
<p>this is a test Paragraph for both Development & Production</p>

@{var body = "this is a test Paragraph for both Development & Production";}
<p>@body</p>

@{var body2 = new HtmlString("this is a test Paragraph for both Development & Production");}
<p>@body2</p>
```

If you render this page you'll notice that the first paragraph does not get encoded, whereas the second paragraph will get encoded as it is encoding the output of a variable. Then the 3rd example will produce the same output as the first as it uses the special HtmlString which assumes that the input is safe.

For reference, here is the output from Razor:

```
<p>this is a test Paragraph for both Development & Production</p>
<p>this is a test Paragraph for both Development &amp; Production</p>
<p>this is a test Paragraph for both Development & Production</p>
```

Comment: thanks but is there a way to encode everything in the page by default wither it is @ block or normal P or any HTML element block ?

Comment: No, Razor was designed to be a very simple view engine that extended HTML. This means that valid HTML is still required to be written. If you have cases where you are requiring people to write HTML that don't know what's valid or not you should look at building a simple CMS type functionality or running some sort of HTML validator prior to check-in.

Answer (score 3):

Razor will only escape output from `@` blocks.

You still need to escape literal markup yourself.
Firebug shows `&amp;` because the browser is smart enough to correctly interpret your invalid markup.

Answer (score -1):

Firebug will automatically HTML encode some things when it displays them in the viewer. This is misleading. Viewing source shows what is actually output by your site.

Comment: That's not quite true.  The browser is automatically fixing up the invalid markup; Firebug is simply echoing the DOM.